# ensuring that @escaping function safely removed from memory

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to understand how memory managed while using escaping before and after calling the closure function

The code is here prints address everytime diferent before and after closure call:

```
  func doSomething(using closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2, execute: {
            withUnsafePointer(to: closure.self) { print("\($0)") } //before call
            closure()
            withUnsafePointer(to: closure.self) { print("\($0)") } //after call
        })
        withUnsafePointer(to: closure.self) { print("\($0)") } //1
    }

0x00007ffee4641ec8 //1
0x00007ffee4642a60 //before call
2021-01-22 20:04:10.480544+0300 test1[64290:1381685] doSomething 1 // ssome output
2021-01-22 20:04:10.480845+0300 test1[64290:1381685] doSomething 2 // ssome output
0x00007ffee4642a48 //last call
```

Comment: What's the exact problem here and what are you trying to achieve ?
`withUnsafePointer` is useful for calling Objective-C APIs that take in parameters by const pointer. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: the address of closure changes, but i think that closure not removing itself from memory after function end,, so how can i track if closure function that i passed safely removed from memory?

Comment: you should more look into retain cycles than check closure addresses. Check if objects you are passing to this closure are not causing retain cycles. Read a bit more about "[weak self]"

Comment: only a print function inside the closure

Comment: Using weak and unowned is the only way to make 100% sure your reference type doesn't hang around in memory for longer than necessary. OK

Comment: I don't understand this last "longer than necessary." There's no universal meaning of "necessary" in this context. Whether `weak self` makes sense here depends on your situation. Swift forces you to think about the ownership graph; you can't avoid that. `withUnsafePointer` doesn't mean anything in this context.

Comment: Add some more `print` calls and you'll see that the address always changes. It has nothing to do with whether you call it or not. More importantly, it has nothing to do when anything captured by the closure is released. You need to think about the reference cycles; it has nothing to do with calls to `withUnsafePointer`.